# NSSortDescriptor -- sort by intValue with 0 at the end

Tags: objective-c, nssortdescriptor

I would like to sort an array using NSSortDescriptor, based on a field's intValue. This works perfectly using the following code:

```
        descriptor2 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lowerPrice.floatValue" ascending:YES];
```

The only issue is that this field either contains a value no matter what, so some of the values are 0. But, in my ranking, the 0's should come as absolute last. Basically, 0.1 should be first, all the way up to let's say 50, and then the 0's. But using floatValue in ascending order, I obviously get the 0's first.

What is the most elegant and simple way to solve this?

Comment: I'd suggest to use a `NSComparisonResult` instead and a block to sort, but it's not possible if you are using that sort to CoreData.

Comment: You could use `sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:comparator:` and write your custom comparator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` which takes a block which is called to compare pairs of elements and return their order. In the block first test for zeros and return the appropriate ordering (two zeros are equal, a zero is greater than anything else), if there are no zeros return based on true numerical ordering.

HTH